# Any successor to “Open all links” of Thunderbird?

Tags: debian, thunderbird, imap, url, offlineimap

For the ancient Thunderbird 1.5, there was an add-on “Open all links”, which, according to its description, opened “all http(s) links in an e-mail message with a single click”. A development of this add-on apparently stopped in 2007; this add-on no longer works.

How to get the same functionality (open all URLs in an HTML e-mail with a single click or few clicks) in a more modern Thunderbird, say, from version 102 onward?  I could also consider other modern e-mail clients for Linux, specifically, for Debian.